# Find information 365 days ago (hive) or (impala)

Tags: sql, date, hive, impala

Please tell me how to find information for the last 365 days from the current day in hive.
Found such a function for months

```
select * from table 
where operdate>=add_months(current_date,-12)
```

but for days I don’t know.
And if you know, please write how you can do it through impala.

Answer (score 1):

Use date_add or date_sub function

```
date_add(current_date, -365)
```

or

```
date_sub(current_date, 365)
```

See [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf) and [Impala manual](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__date_add).